# Unexpected None in python print statement

Tags: python, output

I'm trying to print out a list of nodes connected to other nodes so I can view them for debugging some python code revolving around graphs. I'm doing this for practice so I'm setting up nodes/edges/groups myself.

I've tried printing out the connections with my function inside of the myNode class using a for each type loop. But I get different output if I specify the index of the array and call the same method on it.

```py
def print_connections(self):
        for node in self.connections:
            print(node.name, end = " ")
```

...

```py
for node in nodes:
        node.print_connections()
        print(" ") # so I can have a newline in between groups
print(nodes[1].print_connections())
```

The for/each has good output, or appears to be good:

```
2 5 3 0
```

which differs from the line with the indexed print:

```
2 5 3 0 None
```

Is this expected behavior in python? How can I get around this?

Comment: Can you post some code to see what data is causing this behavior?

Comment: The `None` is the return value from `nodes[1].print_connection()` You don't need to wrap it in `print()`. You call print inside the method, remember.

Comment: `print_connections` returns `None`, therefore, when you print it's return value, it will print `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `print_connections(self)` doesn't return any value, thus return `None`, and what you're trying to do is with `print(nodes[1].print_connections())` is to print the returned value by `nodes[1].print_connections()`, which is going to be `None`,
so what you should do instead is just,

```
for node in nodes:
        node.print_connections()
        print(" ") 
nodes[1].print_connections()
```